# AWS Lambda - Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, faunadb

I have a simple lambda function which calculates a result asynchronously. I can log the result and it seems to be correct but for some reason the lambda function doesn't return successfully, like I am getting a timeout. If you look at the timestamps you can see that the result is calculated way before the timeout. The weird thing is that it works fine when I am using axios but whenever I use fauna it doesn't work anymore, but it does log the correct result... I have been sitting on this problem for days and have no clue what to do. I am using the serverless framework along with this [template](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/tree/master/lib/plugins/create/templates/aws-nodejs-typescript).

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "2021-03-10T07:11:11.567Z 0180b87e-e01f-4527-8c7e-4c1dd5e3e354 Task timed out after 6.01 seconds"
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 0180b87e-e01f-4527-8c7e-4c1dd5e3e354 Version: $LATEST
2021-03-10T07:11:05.811Z    0180b87e-e01f-4527-8c7e-4c1dd5e3e354    INFO    Sending response: { statusCode: 200, body: '{"result":100}' }
END RequestId: 0180b87e-e01f-4527-8c7e-4c1dd5e3e354
REPORT RequestId: 0180b87e-e01f-4527-8c7e-4c1dd5e3e354  Duration: 6007.06 ms    Billed Duration: 6000 ms    Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 76 MB  Init Duration: 205.66 ms    
2021-03-10T07:11:11.567Z 0180b87e-e01f-4527-8c7e-4c1dd5e3e354 Task timed out after 6.01 seconds
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue. Within the handler I set the context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false. Alternatively when using middy you can use this [middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@middy/do-not-wait-for-empty-event-loop)